# How to render custom component in command bar (UI Fabric)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric

I tried many ways to render the custom component in command Bar component but not getting success. give me the idea it is possible or its limitation of command Bar component.

```js
import { CommandBar } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/CommandBar';
const items: ICommandBarItemProps[] = [{
        key: "topicName",
        text: displayTitle,
        disabled: true,
        buttonStyles: {
            textContainer: {
                color: colorBlack
            },
            label: {
                fontWeight: "bold"
            },
            rootDisabled: {
                backgroundColor: colorWhite
            }
        },
    },
    // in here i want to render custom component (just after topicName)
]; 
<CommandBar items = {items}
farItems = {farItems} />
```

I tried this way also but getting an error.

`{
    key: 'custom',
    onRender: (item: any) => <div>Custom</div>
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each item of `CommandBar` has `commandBarButtonAs` property that is used just for what you need.

Documentation: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/commandbar#ICommandBarItemProps

An example:

```
<CommandBar items=[
    {
        key: 'button',
        onClick: () => ({}),
        commandBarButtonAs: () => (<Button />)
    }
] />
```

Comment: I am talking about a custom component, not a button component.

Comment: Well use your custom component instead of <Button> then? It was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me:

```
      {
        key: 'divider',
        onRender: () => <div style={{margin: '5px 0', width: '2px', background: '#ddd'}} > </div>
      },
```

I'm using this in this codepen: https://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/vPzZpQ?editors=0010